# filter out rows based on condition on multiple files in folder

Tags: r, awk

How do I filter out the rows that contains any value other than `0` in the column named `mism`?

```
freq_mir_seq                                mir_seq                                 seq                     name         freq   mir          start  end mism      add     t5      t3      s5      s3      DB      ambiguity
0_hsa-miR-143-3p_TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT    hsa-miR-143-3p_TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT  TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT seq_100006_x0   0   hsa-miR-143-3p  61  81  6AT u-TT    0   0   AGTCTGAG    GCTCAGGA    miRNA   1
5_hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA    hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA  GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA seq_100012_x5   5   hsa-miR-10a-5p  22  43  1GT u-A 0   u-G TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
126_hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG  hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG  GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG seq_100013_x126 126 hsa-miR-10a-5p  22  44  1GT 0   0   0   TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
23_hsa-miR-1296-5p_TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT hsa-miR-1296-5p_TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT    TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT    seq_100019_x23  23  hsa-miR-1296-5p 16  35  0   0   0   u-CC    TGGGTTAG    CTCCTTTA    miRNA   1
3_hsa-miR-887-3p_GTGAACGGGCGCCATCCCGAGGCTT  hsa-miR-887-3p_GTGAACGGGCGCCATCCCGAGGCTT    GTGAACGGGCGCCATCCCGAGGCTT   seq_100029_x3   3   hsa-miR-887-3p  48  72  0   0   0   d-CTT   TGGAGTGA    GAGGCTTT    miRNA   1
17_hsa-miR-10a-5p_ACCCGGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG    hsa-miR-10a-5p_ACCCGGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG   ACCCGGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG  seq_10002_x17   17  hsa-miR-10a-5p  23  44  5GT 0   d-T 0   TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
```

I tried:

```
df[df$mism != 0,]
```

I have a folder with 100 files which look the same, how do I run this command on all files at the same time? Is it possible in R?  The filenames are `Miraligner_*.txt.mirna`   where `*` differ between files.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct.  Can you explain why it is not working?

Comment: My guess is `mism` is a character vector.  Have you tried `df[df$mism != "0", ]`?

Comment: @SamThomas It should work. `v1 <- c('ab', 0, 24, 'b1'); v1[v1!=0]#[1] "ab" "24" "b1"`

Comment: Sorry, yeah it seems to worked anyway. Please see my updated question

Comment: So, your question is different now. Try `files <- list.files(); lst <- lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x, header=TRUE)); lapply(lst, function(x) x[x$mism!=0,])`

Comment: Ah, thanks @akrun, that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be all you need:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i} $(f["mism"])' Miraligner_*.txt.mirna
freq_mir_seq                                mir_seq                                 seq                     name         freq   mir          start  end mism      add     t5      t3      s5      s3      DB      ambiguity
0_hsa-miR-143-3p_TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT    hsa-miR-143-3p_TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT  TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT seq_100006_x0   0   hsa-miR-143-3p  61  81  6AT u-TT    0   0   AGTCTGAG    GCTCAGGA    miRNA   1
5_hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA    hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA  GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA seq_100012_x5   5   hsa-miR-10a-5p  22  43  1GT u-A 0   u-G TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
126_hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG  hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG  GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG seq_100013_x126 126 hsa-miR-10a-5p  22  44  1GT 0   0   0   TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
17_hsa-miR-10a-5p_ACCCGGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG    hsa-miR-10a-5p_ACCCGGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG   ACCCGGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG  seq_10002_x17   17  hsa-miR-10a-5p  23  44  5GT 0   d-T 0   TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
```

To create new, separate output files named `Miraligner_foo.txt.mirna.out` for each input file `Miraligner_foo.txt.mirna`, you could do:

```
awk 'FNR==1{out=FILENAME".out"; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i} $(f["mism"]){print > out}' Miraligner_*.txt.mirna
```

If you aren't using GNU awk then you might get a "too many open files" error from the above so then you'd just need to close the last file before opening the next one:

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(out); out=FILENAME".out"; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i} $(f["mism"]){print > out}' Miraligner_*.txt.mirna
```

Comment: Does this remove the rows which does not have 0? What is the output?

Comment: Does it run on multiple files @Ed Morton

Comment: Sorry, but I would like one output for each input.

Comment: awk 'FNR==1{out=FILENAME".out"; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i} $(f["mism"]){print > out}' Miraligner_*.txt.mirna
awk: Miraligner_185R.txt.mirna.out makes too many open files
 input record number 1, file Miraligner_185R.txt.mirna
 source line number 1

Comment: You wouldn't have that problem with GNU awk as it manages the open files for you internally. I added the workaround for non-gawk to the bottom of my answer. I'm now removing my comments above to clean up.